# '#define AP_MODULE_DECLARE(type) type' in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, apache

Why does the apache source have:

```
#define AP_MODULE_DECLARE(type) type
```

What is the advantage of using, for example, this form:

```
AP_CORE_DECLARE(void) ap_add_per_dir_conf(server_rec *s, void *dir_config);`
```

vs

```
void ap_add_per_dir_conf(server_rec *s, void *dir_config);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that other definitions are possible for those macros. *include/ap_config.h* has the following (with some indentation added by me):

```
#if !defined(WIN32) || defined(AP_MODULE_DECLARE_STATIC)
...
#  if defined(WIN32)
#    define AP_MODULE_DECLARE(type)            type __stdcall
#  else
#    define AP_MODULE_DECLARE(type)            type
#  endif
...
#else
...
#  define AP_MODULE_DECLARE(type)          __declspec(dllexport) type __stdcall
...
#endif
```

Here, `AP_MODULE_DECLARE` is used to add `__stdcall` (which specifies a particular calling convention) and/or `__declspec(dllexport)` (which is related to exporting the function as part of the interface of a shared library).

Note that e.g. the `__declspec(dllexport)` won't be added if `AP_MODULE_DECLARE_STATIC` is defined. My guess (which might not be entirely accurate as I'm not familiar with this code) is that it's related to linking a module as a static library, in which case `__declspec(dllexport)` wouldn't make sense.

If you're wondering what "dso" stands for in the comments in that file, it's for *dynamic shared object*. It's basically a shared library, though Apache seems to reserve the term *shared library* for things that aren't loaded at runtime using `dlopen(3)`.

Comment: thanks! I am trying to learn c++ by, among others, reading open source code. Do you have any tips regarding this?

Comment: @user1092646: Look for some project that seems interesting and see if there's any work to do. You could check bug trackers or IRC for example. Another thing which I sometimes do is to pick some minor bug in some application that I'd usually just shrug off and try to get to the bottom of what causes it (and either fix it or report my findings). That can teach you a lot.